# Removing new lines from text file in order for text to appear on a single line using awk,tr or sed

Tags: linux, text-processing

How do we remove newlines in a test.txt file so that the text now appears on a single line using tr,awk or sed?

E.g

```
My name is mo
Learning linux
live in CAD
```

If I want that text to appear on one line and save it to a new file called passed.txt. What command should I run?

Comment: `tr -d '\n' <test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk '{ printf "%s",$0 }' file > passed.txt # print each line ($0) of file with no new lines
```

With tr:

```
tr -d '\n' < file > passed.txt # Use -d to delete new lines (\n)
```

xargs and printf is also an option:

```
xarg printf "%s" < file > passed.txt # Redirect file into printf and print each default space variable without new lines.
```

Output is redirected to passed.txt with each example